# VLC menu font size changes drastically when moved to secondary monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, fonts, vlc

I have had this problem for many months now. The VLC menu font size increases several times when I move the VLC window from my primary screen to secondary screen. [Here's my screen recording to show what's happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Vxg.jpg)
This problem only happens with VLC, no other application displays this behavior. I have uninstalled VLC, deleted all the vlc config and cache files from my .config, .local and .cache directories and then reinstalled it and the problem still occurs. I vaguely remember that the problem started occurring after I accidentally pressed some key combination while operating VLC.

More details: Distro is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. Resolution for both monitors is same (1920x1080). I tested with another QT app (Audacious) and it doesn't display the problem described for vlc.

Comment: You haven't given us much to work with, I don't know your release though I can assume a desktop (not server, image looks like 18.04 desktop with gnome but it's better to be told as others can be made to look like that too).  VLC is Qt based; so does it occur with other Qt apps?? are the two screens the same resolution?   I'd test another Qt based app to see if it performs the same, if it does I'd explore your Qt settings (which are read along with GTK+ settings & app can decide which to follow when they differ)

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question to add the details.

Comment: `audacious` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/audacious) is GTK+2 and not Qt

Comment: I installed audacious from source with Qt enabled with GTK+2 disabled. I also tried Telegram which is supposed to use Qt and that also doesn't display this problem.